# Removing specific vendor css from generated Microsoft SPA Template VS2017 webpack

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I've created a couple of SPA projects using the Microsoft templates.

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

Then running:

```
dotnet new angular
```

or

```
dotnet new aurelia
```

Both projects generate file named `webpack.config.vendor.js` which looks like the following (from angular sample):

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        entry: {
            vendor: [
                '@angular/animations',
                '@angular/common',
                '@angular/compiler',
                '@angular/core',
                '@angular/forms',
                '@angular/http',
                '@angular/platform-browser',
                '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
                '@angular/router',
                'bootstrap',
                'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'es6-shim',
                'es6-promise',
                'event-source-polyfill',
                'jquery',
                'zone.js',
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
        },
        entry: { vendor: ['aspnet-prerendering'] },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

Now I want to remove Bootstrap from the equation.  I've tried removing the following lines from entry->bootstrap:

```
'bootstrap',
'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
```

But bootstrap still appears in the final vendor.css.  I'm still getting up to speed with WebPack (slowly).

What do I need to do to remove `bootstrap` from the vendor.css output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In package.json in your root folder.

add

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm install && npm run webpack",
    "webpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js && webpack"
  },
```

In webpack.config.vendor.js

```
        entry: {
            vendor: [
                'aurelia-event-aggregator',
                'aurelia-fetch-client',
                'aurelia-framework',
                'aurelia-history-browser',
                'aurelia-logging-console',
                'aurelia-pal-browser',
                'aurelia-polyfills',
                'aurelia-route-recognizer',
                'aurelia-router',
                'aurelia-templating-binding',
                'aurelia-templating-resources',
                'aurelia-templating-router',
                **//Remove the following two lines**
                'bootstrap',
                'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'jquery'
            ],
        },
```

then run the following command.

```
npm run webpack
```

Comment: That does the trick.  On another note, given that you remove the bootstrap references in the `vendor` configuration in webpack.config.vendor.js, if there is no CSS picked up, then vendor.css will not be regenerated.  So in my scenario, if I comment out bootstrap, vendor.css still has the bootstrap from the previous run.  Is there a nice way to ensure vendor.css will be empty if there is no css?

Comment: I've not used webpack extensively, I'm still pretty new to this so maybe some one else with more experience can chime in. Best bet would just to delete everything in it manually. Here's a plugin that you might be potentially interested in. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack

Answer (score 1):

user8454147 gave the right answer. But it doesn't work for `dotnet new angular` scaffold for example. File vendor.css just doesn't regenerate. Try to do this for make it work: remove this two lines from vendor array:

```
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
```

and add new line with some css. It is very important! For example, I add material design css file:

```
'material-design-lite/material.css',
```

Only after that run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`. Magic, vendor.css recreated. I think it's just a bug or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. The accepted answer didn't work for me.. adding your steps solved my problem with the Aurelia template and adding material design.